# Jar File does not behave like in the IDE

Tags: java, swing

Hi is my first time to ask something.

I make a little java program that it runs properly when i run it from IDE, but when i run it as jar file it don't run properly. The first icon is from IDE and the second as Jar.

Comment: Can you please post a bit more information. We can't solve a problem when we even don't know the IDE, what you are trying to do and if there are errors. Please edit you question. These help articles may help you: how to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  To ask a question we can answer, we need a lot of the information that you probably don't think about.  The best approaches are to provide a very small example program of the specific problem you are encountering, with a description of what you get when you run it, and what you expected to get (but didn't).  Remember we are on the other side of the internet, so try to make your problem clearly understood by a complete stranger (without the benefit of the stranger knowing what you already know).  Thank you!  Good luck!

Comment: *"the first icon"* What icon?

Comment: @Andreas *and the second as* What icon**s**?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm starting small here. Hopefully OP would realize that both are missing and fix both at the same time, but we'll see.

Comment: “…it don't run properly” We need more information than that.  What were you expecting to see?  What did you see instead?  (My first guess is that you’re relying on a relative file name.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a guess, but this is a pretty common problem.

In Java, executable jar files don't pay attention to the class path.

They have an internal MANIFEST.MF entry where you can specify the dependent JAR libraries; but, those libraries must be in the directories encoded into the executable JAR file.

If you don't specify the dependent libraries, then when running the executable JAR file (which can be done by clicking on the JAR file's icon) you will get class not found exceptions.

Comment: If the question can't be answered without guessing, you ought to vote to close and comment asking the OP to provide more details.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica Only been doing this for 10 years now, please assume I really know the rules.  Perhaps I just wanted to make SO a little less rough for a new user, who doesn't know the rules.  And this is one of the dark corner-cases of executable JAR files that most people discover the hard way, and 90% of the executable jar file core problems on SO over the last decade.

Comment: ok the IDE is when i run my program from the platform of NetBeans all the results are ok.but when i run it as a jar the results are not the same. it is a simple readtext program import from url a specific line and take some data out to a jpanel.

Comment: @Tolis Executable JAR files don't use the classpath, so they will not work the same as your IDE JAR files, even if they have the same contents.

Comment: thank you for your comment. The problem is that the results are not the same while i run only one method reading specific char and display two strings.it makes me wonder if the Manifest.mf also effects inside methods

Comment: while(k < inputLine.length()-(first*3)){if(inputLine.contains("alt")){first = inputLine.indexOf("alt");end = inputLine.indexOf("/>",first+k);start=end;                     endsec = inputLine.indexOf("€",first+k);bstart=endsec;                while(inputLine.charAt(start)!= '=')start--;while(inputLine.charAt(bstart)!= '>')                         bstart--;store= inputLine.substring(start+2, end-1);                   price=inputLine.substring(bstart+1,endsec+1);}k = end;                            stores.add(store);prices.add(price);}   THE CODE OF METHOD

Comment: @Tolis Please learn how to edit your question.  The code goes into the question at the top, not in this place, where it cannot be read easily.